# No consigo guardar dato en variable. (PHP y MySQLi)

Tags: php, mysqli

Es un registro en PHP, el problema está en la función que comprueba si una persona está registrada o no, siempre muestra el dato en Null.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['entrar'])) {    
session_start();
$conexion = new Conexion();
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
$datosPersona = $conexion->comprobarPersona($email, $pass);      
if ($datosPersona != null) {
    $p = new Persona($datosPersona[0], $datosPersona[1], $datosPersona[2], $datosPersona[3]);
    $_SESSION["resultado"] = $p;
    header('Location: bienvenido.php');     
} else {
    $_SESSION["resultado"] = "Usuario o password incorrectos";
    header('Location: index.php');      
}
```

Si nos vamos al comprobarPersona() de Conexion nos encontramos esto:

```
function comprobarPersona($email, $pass) {
    $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM personas WHERE email='" . $email . " AND pass='" . $pass . "'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $usuario = null;
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $usuario = array($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3]);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $usuario;
```

He comprobado todo y ya no sé qué me falla. Siempre se queda en Null $usuario.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Ponlo así a ver que tal: `$usuario [] = array($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3]);`. Si no funciona, evalúa si hay algo en las filas poniendo por ejemplo `var_dump($row);` dentro del `while`. Una cosa, con `mysqli`
 puedes mapear el resultado a una clase también. En tu caso sería mucho mejor mapear el resultado a la clase `Persona`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intenta asi para validar que se este ejecutando la query:

```
function comprobarPersona($email, $pass) {
    $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM personas WHERE email='{$email}' AND pass='{$pass}' ");

    $usuario = null;
   !$stmt->execute()? die($this->conexion->error()) : "";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $usuario = array($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3]);
    }

    $stmt->close();
return $usuario;
```